# What does it mean for a factorization to be unique up to unit factors?

Tags: abstract-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

"If $R$ is a UFD, then the factorization of any element as a finite product of irreducible factors is unique up to within order and unit factors."

One could argue that this means that if for instance $ab$ and $cd$ are factorizations of a number into irreducible element, then there is a unit $u$ such that $au = c$ and
$b$ = $d$. This seems fishy too me.

I think it means that if for instance $ab$ and $cd$ are factorizations of a number into irreducible elements, then there are units $u$ and $v$, with $uv = 1$ such that $au = c$ and $bv = d$. The reason beeing that given a factorization one could multiply by $1 = uv$ and then multiply $u$ with one irreducible element and $v$ with another, thus maybe changing the factors.

What is the correct way to interpret the statement?

Edit: Changed the title

Comment: The original statement says "unit factors" *plural* and your restatement artificially changes this to "a unit factor" *singular*. The problem exists before you even get to interpreting the statement: you've changed the statement itself.

Comment: Ok, say 3 unit factors then. $u$,$v$,$w$ where $uv = 1$. That would make the same problem wouldn't it?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Where's the problem?

Comment: Am I correct when assuming that you are talking about this statement? " One could argue that this means that if for instance $ab$ and $cd$ are factorizations of a number into irreducible element, then there is a unit $u$ such that $au = c$ and
$b$ = $d$. This seems fishy too ."

Comment: The original statement I mentioned is the one you have in quotes in your question. It includes the phrase "unit factors." Your artificial restatement of it is in the title of this question, it includes the phrase "a unit factor." The statement that begins "One could argue..." is also a misstatement, because it invokes "a unit" singular rather than units plural to identify ostensibly different factorizations as actually the same. You can't *change* a claim, point out a problem with the altered claim, and then blame the original claim for the issue - that's dishonest.

Comment: IMHO the formulation *unique up to \[some manipulation]* $X$ does not mean that every $X$ gives a valid solution, but that all valid solutions are in the same equivalence class associated with $X$. In that sense, the cited statement is correct. That the product can be changed by an unrestricted admission of unit factors is true, but immaterial.

Comment: @sea turtles Yes, I agree that I had the wrong statement in the title of the question. But still, say that you multiply by several units,  say an odd number of units, the problem is still the same.

Comment: What problem? ${}$

Comment: @sea turtles Ok, I think that what the statement is saying is that it is unique up to unit factors, because you could multiply by $1 = uv$. But could you multiply by $uvw$, where $u$,$v$,and $w$ are units, where $uv$ = 1 and still not change its value?

Comment: @ccorn This is my idea too, but I wanted to check it, in case I had misunderstood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're exactly right. Let $R$ be a UFD, then you could state the unique factorization condition as follows:

For any $a\in R$, let $[a]$ denote the set $\{au : u\in R^\times\}$.

Then if $a_1a_2\cdots a_n = b_1b_2\cdots b_m$ with $a_i,b_i$ irreducible, then $n = m$, and there is some permutation $\sigma\in S_n$ such that $[a_i] = [b_{\sigma(i)}]$ for every $i$.